# CSS left float with variable content and windows width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a variable windows size and a header with 3 floating blocks.
The first is floating to right with fixed width, the second is floating left with fixed width. The last (varleft) is floating left with variable length content.

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="right">test</div>
  <div id="left">test</div>
  <div id="varleft">very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text </div>
</div>
```

I want to prevent this third block from going under other blocks while it grows in its width, moreover, I want to give it a second line for long content, and then truncate string with ellipsis.

These blocks are block of bootstrap nav-header so I cannot use other but floats to move them.

This is a text example for growing text:
https://jsfiddle.net/mjq2tum0/

This is the result I wish (excepting for fixed width and one-line ellipsis):
https://jsfiddle.net/o90sm39L/

Comment: do your header have a background-color (not an image) ? if yes, I might have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in your css:

```
#varleft {
   max-width: calc(100% - 306px);
}
```

Comment: How do you respond to this request `moreover, I want to give it a second line for long content, and then truncate string with ellipsis.` ?

Comment: You can read about it at -> http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/

Answer (score 1):

> I want to prevent this third block from going under other blocks while it grows in its width, moreover, I want to give it a second line for long content, and then truncate string with ellipsis.

Here is solution. 
**Note that it will work only if you have a plain background color.**

Code more than inspired by [this awesome article](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)

If it's not a problem for you :

**1.** I find more practical to use `box-sizing: border-box;` :

```
#header > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**2.** Change the width of your div `varleft` :

```
  width: calc(100% - 300px); // 100% minus the width of #right and #left
```

*Now, your div `varleft` won't go under the other blocks*

**3.** Add a position and an overflow to `varleft` :

```
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
```

**4.** Use pseudo element to create the ellipsis `...` and to create a div that will hide the `...` if not necessary

```
#varleft:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#varleft:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
}
```

**Here is a snippet:**

```js
$(function(){
  var ranchr = "A BCDE FGHI JKLMN OPQRS TUVWX YZabcd efghijklm nopqr stuvwx yz0123 456789";
 setInterval(function(){
    if($("#varleft").text().length>100)
        $("#varleft").text("");
   $("#varleft").append(ranchr.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ranchr.length)));
  },100);
});
```

```css
#header{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
#header > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#right{
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
#left{
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
#varleft{
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#varleft:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#varleft:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
<div id="right">test</div>
<div id="left">test</div>
<div id="varleft"></div>
</div>
```